# How to add custom item inside DropDownMenuItem in this new version

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-dropdownmenu

in this app I have the following custom composable item

```
@Composable
fun PriorityItem(priority: Priority) {
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(PRIORITY_INDICATOR_SIZE)) {
            drawCircle(color = priority.color)
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = LARGE_PADDING), text = priority.name,
            style = Typography.headlineMedium,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
        )
    }
}
```

I am trying to add it inside DropDownMenu repeated 3 times as three drop-down menu items, but in this version, the DropDownMenuItem doesn't have a row scope to which I can add my custom item `PriorityItem`

```
@Composable
fun SortAction(onSortClicked: (Priority) -> Unit) {

    var expanded by remember() {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    IconButton(onClick = {expanded = true}) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_filter_list_24),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.sort_tasks)
        )

        DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false}) {
            DropdownMenuItem(text = { /*TODO*/ },
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ }){
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the following image is exactly what I want to do but the tutorial is old

[image]

Answer (score 2):

hay there did you found anything about how to do it ?
i've paid some money for this course :)

i figured you just moved on after 2 months but to anyone who hasn't
you must do this

```
text = { PriorityItem(priority = Priority.LOW)  }
```

just pass whatever you want to show inside the text parameter

if you wanna show text make sure you use the "Text" Compose function otherwise it wont show
like use

```
(text = { Text("your string") }, onClick = { expended = false })
```

i hope someone find this useful :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35297274)